# Как разрешить ввод только заглавных латинских букв и пробелов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В программе CRM, пытаюсь настроить поле, чтобы вводились только заглавные буквы на английском.
Сделал так: `[A-Z]` - но при вводе строчных также прокатывает
`[A-Z]{3,40}` - Применяется только для первого предложение

Как сделать, чтобы было можно ввести данные только так, например: `VASILIY ANTONOV`?

Comment: Может обозначить начало строки `^` и конец строки `$` что бы выражение проверяло не произвольную ее часть, а целиком

Comment: Возможно следующее:  ^[A-Z]*&

Comment: К сожалению и с этими вариантами не удается также, ввожу заглавными, выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? Можно подробнее? Поле, в которое вы вводите - это разрешенные символы, или запрещенные?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы при вводе в поле, вводились только заглавные буквы, все остальное выдавали ошибку. Вот скрин: http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0426/h_1461700275_3862329_294d7574df.png

Comment: @bakusite кроме букв - пробелы или спец символы могут быть?

Comment: @splash58 только пробелы и заглавные буквы

Comment: так пробелы тоже надо добавитьь - `^[A-Z ]*$`

Comment: а если надо, чтобы хотябы одна буква была, поменяйте звездочку на плюс

Comment: @splash58 большое спасибо всем!

Answer (score 2):

Вполне вероятно, что в этой ORM используется проверка соответствию регулярному выражению с обязательно включенным флагом `IGNORE_CASE`.
Можно попробовать выключить этот флаг, если ORM использует движок PCRE:

```
^(?-i)[A-Z ]+$
```

Регулярное выражение читается так: отключаем `IGNORE_CASE`, `[A-Z]` или пробел минимум один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Если планируется проверять *не пустое* поле со словами, *написанными заглавными буквами* и *разделенными одним пробелом*, тогда подойдет такое регулярное выражение:

```
(^[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*$)
```

Если необходимо разрешить пустое поле, тогда можно сделать так:

```
(^[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*|$)
```