# Как убрать все слова полностью состоящие из заглавных букв?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Нужно убрать аббревиатуры и слова состоящие из одной заглавной буквы из текста.

В моем тексте присутствуют слова такие как:

```
СНТ класс Б Колодец
```

Конечный результат должен быть:

```
класс Колодец
```

Comment: исправил метки: ни к языку программирования *r*, ни к программе *r studio* вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: Почему же не имеет, если я в этой программе работаю? Все же коды везде отличаются

Comment: @Anna покажите код, как вы сейчас убираете слова "где вторая буква заглавная".

Comment: Приведите пример строки со словами, которые нужно удалить, и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка для поиска всех заглавных букв:

- [Регулярное выражение для поиска слов из заглавных букв русского языка](https://toster.ru/q/317180) — используйте регулярное выражение `[А-ЯЁ]+`
- [Как разрешить ввод только заглавных латинских букв](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517530/213987) — используйте регулярное выражение `[AZ]+`

Но... вы идёте не в ту степь с регулярками.

Скачайте [словарь аббревиатур Артемия Лебедева](http://www.sokr.ru/) и используйте его - это будет более правильный способ.

А то вы регулярками насчитаете в предложении "Я ХОЧУ САЛО!!" целых две аббревиатуры, а то и все три.

Раз вы знаете такую программу как r studio, то понимаете как работать с данными. После составления списка аббревиатур их поиск в тексте сводится к тривиальному совпадению.

И никаких регулярок. (Место для классической шутки про [regexp на xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1171/))

---

Updated Про уточнённый вопрос. Если у вас в тексте встречаются не только аббревиатуры, но ещё и какие-то слова характерные для вашей предметной области, типа "План Б", "Гайка Д", то я бы рекомендовал делать вычистку в несколько проходов.

Зависит от требуемой вами точности. В простейшем случае вы можете не заниматься тем, чтобы учитывать падежи (план Б, по плану Б) и рассчитывать, что буквы русского алфавита, которые составляют односложные слова ("А", "Я", "О", "У", "И", "К" и т.п.) не будут попадаться в ваших текстах в плохо распознаваемых словосочетаниях.

Но если вам надо строго и качественно... О-о-о, тут мы подходим к таким вещам, как разбиение текста на лексемы и выделение фактов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто несколько ссылок для ознакомления:

- [Разметка именованных сущностей](https://habr.com/en/post/388061/)
- [FactRuEval 2016](https://habr.com/en/company/abbyy/blog/273965/)
- [Открытый корпус русского языка](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php)

Comment: @Kromster Поясните, почему не по адресу? Убирать аббревиатуры - я сказал, что СЛОВО написанное заглавными - не всегда является АББРЕВИАТУРОЙ (попробуйте убрать регуляркой из моего комментария аббревиатуры, а не слова, состоящие целиком из заглавных букв). Всё по существу вопроса, всё по делу. И даже упоминание о том, что регулярки - это как правило признак плохой архитектуры - это юмор, а не возмущение.

Comment: Я с Вами согласнна, что упустила момент о том, что не все слова написанные загравными - аббревиатуры. Просто я таких фраз не находила в данном случае, но для дальнейшего более точного анализа Ваш способ вернее. Спасибо!

Comment: Но у меня так же могут присутствовать слова из одной буквы заглавной, например, "класс Б", где "Б" нужно тоже исключить из текста для дальнейшего анализа. Так что скорее всего, нужно будет делать в несколько действий.

Comment: @Anna дополняйте вопрос примерами )

Comment: Стало лучше, спасибо! Остался только 1 момент: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\s|^)[A-ZА-Я]+?(?=$|[\s\.,?!])
```

> `(?<=\s|^)` - проверяем, что перед группой символов стоит либо любой 
>   пробельный символ `\s`, либо начало строки `^`.
>   `[A-ZА-Я]+?` - один или более заглавный символ латинского или русского алфавита
>   `(?=$|[\s\.,?!])` - проверяем, что за группой следует конец строки `$` или любой пробельный символ, или знак препинания (.,!?).

Comment: Для определения границы слова есть специальный квантификатор `\b`

Comment: @АндрейNOP,  с кириллическими символами он не работает.

Comment: `\b` определяет границы слова с помощью `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. А `\w` -  это `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. https://regex101.com/r/gqDpNU/1

Comment: Если по вашей ссылке переключить на Python то кириллицу нормально захватывает, в .NET тоже кириллица захватывается, уверены, что в R не будет захватываться. Имхо, в нормальной реализации регулярок это должно работать для любых алфавитов